# Simplify repeated scope attributes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I found myself repeating the following structure too often and I'd like to simplify it:

```
<container>
  <clock property="data"></clock>
  <calendar property="data"></calendar>
  <alert property="data"></alert>
</container>
```

With the relative directive

```
app.directive('clock', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'property': '='
    }
  }
});
```

How could I remove the property="data" from each item and move it eventually at the container level?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `property="data"` in parent directive and make it available through its controller

Your container directive

```
<container property="data">

app.directive('container', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'property': '='
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      this.getData = function(){
        return $scope.property;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And your child directive

```
<clock></clock>    

app.directive('clock', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^container',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, containerCtrl) {
      console.log(containerCtrl.getData());
    }        
  }
});
```

`require` the parent directive and call it's associate method `containerCtrl.getData()` to get your required value.

Check the <kbd>[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nAFGTrOEVbF7YVnBSPH0?p=preview)</kbd>